# Update data in sqlite use int array

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

```
/*
<Update total page>
work: Update total page
input: title, new total page
output: none
*/

public void update_tot_page(String str_title, int int_newPageTot) {
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase(); 

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("page_total", int_newPageTot);    
    //error->
    db.update("booklist", values, "page_total=?", new int[] {int_newPageTot});
    //<-
}
```

I want update total page in `booklist` table. 
I find
        `db.update("booklist", values, "title=?", new String[]{str_title});` is not wrong. 
By the way, why `db.update("booklist", values, "page_total=?", new int[] {int_newPageTot});` is wrong?
How should I **change** this **sentence**?

Answer (score 0):

[the last 2 parameters in](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) `update()` are `whereClause` and `whereArgs`, that's equivalent to a `where clause`, ex, `where id = 10`

```
db.update("booklist", values, "title=?", new String[]{str_title});
```

the above is correct because you are setting new value for `page_total` and condition is `where title=...`

the one below is not correct because `where page_total=newTotal` is not found in DB
**syntax-wise** it's correct, but it will not match a record in db. or it may match one with total = the new total you are trying to set, but this could be not the record you actually want, stick to `title` or use a primary-key (ID)

```
db.update("booklist", values, "page_total=?", new int[] {int_newPageTot});
```

if you really want to do it with page_total: `where page_total=...` you need to pass `currentTotal` too as param to the function and use it in the `update()`

```
db.update("booklist", values, "page_total=?", new int[] {currentTotal});
```

but again, this may update 2 or 3 or even more records as they all have `page_total` equals `currentTotal` param, and this could be wrong (for you)